# Why are the images I am downloading from S3 not appearing on only 1 persons phone?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an app, and it currently has about 10 beta users on it.

Out of 10 beta users, only one person is experiencing the following problem:

Profile pictures are not showing up on his phone. I am downloading these profile pictures from AWS S3 us-east-2, and here is the function that I am using to download these pictures:

```
static func downloadProfileImage(username: String, onExists: @escaping (_ image: UIImage) -> Void, onSuccess: @escaping (_ url: Data) -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ error: String) -> Void) {

    let cacheKey = "public_f/" + username + "ProfilePhoto.png"

    if let image = imageCache.object(forKey: cacheKey as NSString) {
        onExists(image)
        return
    }

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = { (task, imageUrl, data, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if error != nil {
                onError(error!.localizedDescription)
                print("Transfer Error: ", error)
                return
            }
            if let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!) {
                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: cacheKey as NSString)
            }

            onSuccess(data!)
            return
        })
    }

    let key = "public_f/" + username + "ProfilePhoto.png"
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    transferUtility.downloadData(
        fromBucket: BUCKETNAME,
        key: key,
        expression: expression,
        completionHandler: completionHandler
        ).continueWith {
            (task) -> AnyObject? in if let error = task.error {
                onError(error.localizedDescription)
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return nil
            }
        return nil;
    }
}
```

When he launches his phone, he does not get any errors printed out nor does the function escape the completion block.

It is only happening to him, 1 out of the 10 people that have the application.

He has an iPhone 8 running the latest version of iOS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression can take in a progress handler

```
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()
expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        print("Progress is \(progress.fractionCompleted)")         
    })
}
```

Is progress being called for that user when download is initiated? does it ever make it to 100%?